# PHP: representing query results

Tags: php, html, css

This is very simple, I’m sorry to bother with it, but I’ve been hours thinking how to do it and I cannot come out with a solution :(

My database query is throwing:

```
ID – NAME – LASTNAME –  SONG —    ALBUM
12 –Bryan – Ferry –  Rescue Me –   Taxi 
12 –Bryan – Ferry –  Just One Look –Taxi 
99 – Nick – Cave –   Wonderful Life – Nocturama
```

The way I need it to be shown in my web page is:

**Bryan Ferry**

Rescue Me (Taxi)

Just One Look (Taxi)

**Nick Cave**

Wonderful Life (Nocturama)

Well I’m in my php’s script, in the  while the query results loop, but I cannot figure out how to go on..

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
//what do I have to do here to get the format I need ?? 
}
```

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: it depends on whether you want some ugly mock solution or a professional one. with the former you'd just print your results in HTML right away (EDIT see below /EDIT) or put it in an assoc. by artist before printing

Comment: +1! This is a good question! Why it has been downvoted? I'm also interested in a professional solution for this kind of situations. The answer from ken clark is ok, but it looks a bit dirty to me. There must be a better answer

Comment: @Alexxus The **[MVC pattern](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Model%20View%20Controller%22)** is a bare minimum to adopt. If one is not using OOP it should also be mimicked for a good basis of separating concerns. Display-specific code goes into so called views, DB-specific code goes into their own modules, etc. and business logic should be virtually free of any environment-specific code (what DB you use, what do you print your results on and in what format, what it is "driven by", and so on). Each module should be as much independent from others as possible (through indirections).

Comment: @Powerslave OOP is the one solution, I agree. An other would be to write a function, which groups your query results into a multidimensional array. I wasn't speaking about MVC. For me it's self explanatory, that people should use that.

Comment: @Alexxus Well, it's nice to see that it is self-explanatory for you, however, unfortunately this is not necessarily true for everyone (for most). Mimicking OOP with procedural code is usually feasible as well as basic decoupling of functionalities via subroutines. Still, a professional solution would employ OOP, and most likely have a presentation layer, an application layer, a business layer and a data access (infrastructure) layer. Avoiding hardcodings and magic values along with employing SoC is very important in anything beyond *helloworld* - hmm... maybe I'll write a series on the subject

Comment: As an easy and dirty solution, you could wrap the DB call into a `findAllSongs()` function that simply puts the rows into an array and returns that. Then a `groupSongsByArtist($songs)` should pack them in an assoc. like `{ $artistName => {$row, $anotherRow, $etc} }`. Next up, a `renderHtml($songsGroupedByArtist)` function would take care of assembling HTML representation of the data. Controlling code would then `renderHtml(groupSongsByArtist(findAllSongs()));`. This is still quite dirty, yet it allows for some flexibility (code reuse, infrastructure changes, different rendering, etc).

Comment: @Alexxus I forgot to mention template engines or simply templating which is pretty much useful as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in PHP this is the way I would do it...

```
$oldid = -999;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($row["id"] != $oldid) {
        echo($row["name"]." ".$row["lastname"]."<br />");
        $oldid = $row["id"];
    }
    echo($row["song"]." (".$row["album"].")<br />");
}
```

Everytime round the loop just check the artist ID against what it was last time. If different print the artist name and update $oldid, otherwise just print the song title

Comment: Ha, ha. "Ugly mock solution", "unprofessional", "dirty". Its simple, it works and it conforms to the (admittedly brief) spec.

Comment: @kenclark And what's so funny about that?

Comment: @kenclark The funny thing is, `works != good`. It is ok as a quick-and-dirty answer to the question, but you should be at least mentioning this fact and that it's use in production code is generally discouraged. It might seem fit for a beginner to write such code and "work on production", but should you try anything serious, it will eventually become a nightmare. Quite sadly, however, almost no PHP learning materials mention good practices over the bad practices that are most often promoted everywhere; this  results in being unaware of the concerning mistakes one does by writing such code.

Comment: @kenclark To name a few problems: *1* Your are making assumptions about the compatibility between PHP and database numeric types. Records may be missed. *2* `mysql_blah` is deprecated. *3* Hardwiring of the DB engine used makes you no good. Are you going to rewrite everything if you need to switch to, say, SQLite? *4* Hardcoded DB structure forces you to rewrite everything whenever the tables change. *5* Hardcoded and inlined HTML. How do you now present, say, a JSON-RPC access to the app? Copy-paste-edit? Not a good idea. *6* Will you rewrite everything to change the HTML appearance? *7* etc

Comment: @Powerslave: And so perfect code that doesn't work would have been a better answer? Its funny but after 30 years in development and support i've never met a customer who didn't mind if it worked or not.
Seriously though, of course there are frameworks and methodologies that could, and maybe should, be used, but I was pitching the answer at the level of the requestor. If they had pitched the question in MVC or OOPs terms I would have answered in kind. 
I look forward to seeing your 'best practice' solution to the question in the near future.

Comment: @kenclark Nobody said that fulfilling funtional requirements is not a must. Also, talking about customers, they nowadays most often expect your products to be not only working but of high quality. *"After 30 years of development"* you should not be upset when someone points out that the above solution is - somewhat admittedly - dirty, really. Moreover you should have suggested it yourself. Beginners today might be colleagues tomorrow. Leaving them unaware of code quality issues does harm to not only themselves but also to those who later would constantly be correcting them.